# VB6 Crystal Reports ActiveX viewer not displaying all export formats

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I am using the Crystal Reports ActiveX viewer (v10) in a VB6 app. 
10/12/2003  01:41 AM           799,944 crviewer.dll

The viewer loads OK and displays the report but the export formats available using the button on the dialog are limited to:

- Crystal Report (RPT)
- Tab seperated text
- Text

I have confirmed that the required export DLLs such as u2fsepv.dll, u2fxls.dll, etc are located in both the windows\system32 and Common files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\bin directories.

I have checked the source code used to load the viewer and it is not limiting export formats in any way that I can see.

Is this a known issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Those DLL's (`u2*.dll`) need to be dropped in `C:\Windows\Crystal`.

**EDIT**

For v8.5, I also install and register:

```
$PROGRAMFILES\Seagate Software\Shared\ExportModeller.dll
$PROGRAMFILES\Seagate Software\Shared\crtslv.dll
```

Note, that the export driver for PDF is not a `u2f*.dll`; I use `crxf_pdf.dll` (which does go in `$WINDIR\Crystal`)

Comment: Thanks @Lynn. Just tried that (also copied them to the app directory) - No difference. Have noticed that the date/time stamps on the u2x dlls not showing up don't look right so am now looking into that - they maybe the 8.5 versions of the DLLs and maybe that is the issue. Funny that the only destination is 'Disk' but other 10.x destination DLLs are present.

Comment: I didn't think that native apps (read: vb6) could use anything newer than cr8.5. When you said you were using cr10, I figured that maybe I've just been wrong all of these years. Any chance I'm right?

Comment: Seems to work ok with VB6. I think the issue is that the run-time files have not been installed properly on the box (some key files that handle the export fns are missing). This is what I am chasing up now. Your initial answer did present me with some deja vu , though. What a nightmare CR is to support!

Comment: I'm going to edit my post to include the locations of the other files that I deliver.